# Firebase Authentication API with php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
<?php

class FirebaseOTPAuthentication {
    private $firebaseConfig;

    public function __construct($config) {
        $this->firebaseConfig = $config;
        $this->initializeFirebase();
        add_shortcode('firebase_otp_authentication', array($this, 'renderHTML'));
    }

    private function initializeFirebase() {
        $firebaseVersion = '8.10.0'; // Adjust the version as needed
    
        wp_enqueue_script('firebase-app', "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/{$firebaseVersion}/firebase-app.js", array(), null, true);
        wp_enqueue_script('firebase-auth', "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/{$firebaseVersion}/firebase-auth.js", array('firebase-app'), null, true);
    
        wp_add_inline_script('firebase-app', 'var firebaseConfig = ' . json_encode($this->firebaseConfig) . '; firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);', 'after');
    }
    
    

    public function renderHTML() {
        ob_start();
        ?>
        <h1>Firebase OTP Authentication</h1>
        <input type="text" id="phoneNumber" placeholder="Enter your phone number">
        <button onclick="sendOTP()">Send OTP</button>
        <input type="text" id="verificationCode" placeholder="Enter OTP">
        <button onclick="verifyOTP()">Verify OTP</button>
        <div id="recaptcha-container"></div> <!-- Add this line for Recaptcha container -->
        <script>
            var firebaseConfig = <?php echo json_encode($this->firebaseConfig); ?>;

            function sendOTP() {
                var phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value;
                var appVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier("recaptcha-container");

                firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, appVerifier)
                    .then(function (confirmationResult) {
                        window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.error("Error sending OTP: ", error);
                    });
            }

            function verifyOTP() {
                var verificationCode = document.getElementById("verificationCode").value;
                confirmationResult.confirm(verificationCode)
                    .then(function (result) {
                        console.log("User signed in: ", result.user);
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.error("Error verifying OTP: ", error);
                    });
            }
        </script>
        <?php
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}

// Firebase configuration
$firebaseConfig = [
    "apiKey" => "",
    "authDomain" => "",
    "projectId" => "",
    "storageBucket" => "",
    "messagingSenderId" => "",
    "appId" => ""
];

// Instantiate the class
$firebaseAuth = new FirebaseOTPAuthentication($firebaseConfig);
```

I am working on custom wordpress plugin...

In this, problem is when I use firebase cdn version 8.10.0 then work ok but when I use latest version 10.7.2 or any version other after 8.10.0 then this not work and give error in console

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at firebase-auth.js:1:1)
> Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
> at test2/:386:277
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' (at firebase-app.js:2539:1)

Please suggest some solution...is this version problem or some other problem?

Answer (score 1):

It might be a version problem, however the term version remains merely unspecified in your question and henceforth this analysis may not answer your question yet.

The error is indeed a Javascript error, more specifically a SyntaxError with the diagnostic message "Unexpected token 'export'". As it is uncaught, it halts that Javascript process (it stops.)

For further analysis on your end and possible solution suggestions that can result from it, please consult the reference question on site: [Getting Unexpected Token Export](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38296667/22873487).

The most straight forward solution, and in this sense it is a version problem, is that you use the version that works: 8.10.0.

As I consider you would not have asked this question if you wouldn't want to use a version higher than 8.10.0 (e.g. 10.7.2 or 9.0.2), you can find more information in another reference question: [unexpected token export firebase-app.js:1590](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69140697/22873487) that has [an answer with the explanation what changed in version 9 and what a solution is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69144022/22873487).

Perhaps you can already apply the following pattern to the basenames in the path component of the script URLs and it works:

```
firebase-*-compat.js ← firebase-*.js
```

(append `-compat` before `.js`)